# Jira comment on issue or create new bug?

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

In Jira, if a Q.A. tester finds a problem with the way a developer has implemented an unreleased feature, should they be logging that as a new bug?  Or is it better for them to note the problems as a comment and re-open the issue?

If they enter it as a comment on the existing issue, then when using the time-tracking features I believe you would have a more accurate impression of how long that issue actually took to implement.  On the other hand, if you create new bugs then you can track how many bugs developers are generating for the number of issues they're working on for quality improvement purposes.

What are the pros and cons to each approach?  Is there a way to achieve both of the benefits I outlined above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in favor of creating a new issue.
In many cases  a bug needs to be reopened cause the root cause has changed.  Probably the developer made a number of assumptions which aren't true anymore in a new version, so the description of the original issue is not 100% correct anymore.

(If the bug needs to be reopened cause the fix is plain wrong, test strategy must be revised.)

I've seen bugs that were reopened 17 times.  If you print out the comments made around this bug, you would end up with a document of more than 20 pages.

Another drawback of being able to reopen a bug is that it makes the workflow unnecessary complex, with a 'Reopened' state and additional transitions ...

Using plugins like JCALP  or JCLP, it is straightforward for the tester to create a new bug out of the previous one.

An advantage of not reopening is that you will be able to report more clearly on 
a certain build

- Number of new bugs
- Number of bugs carried over from previous build(s)
- Number of bugs closed

Francis

Answer (score 1):

My preference as a developer is to have the test engineer had a comment and then attempt to open a discussion with me about the feature. A defect would be one more item on the payload for the release and one more ticket that will require to be addressed in testing verification plan and results.

In Jira, you can add time worked in a ticket so the time can be tracked even when the ticket maybe be looked in several builds/releases before it is marked closed.

Comment: I agree, add a comment and reopen. Tracking another issue is adding an unnecessary level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a new issue for each problem found, and relate the issues created to original feature. In this case, developer is not loosing the context of the problem and has a chance to work on the bugs separately. Of course, it depends on the process you're following, but normally, while testing new feature QA person finds more than 1 bug, I would say, much more. According to the bug Priority, the feature can be accepted or reopened. Plus, looking at the feature, you see the whole bunch of bugs related to it.Sometimes, even not all found bugs are fixed before the feature goes to production. Of course, if the found problem is critical, and new functionality is broken, which means that the feature is not implemented completely,  it should be reopened, without even creating a new issue.